# How do I print the generated QR code using Nayku's library in a pdf file?

Tags: c++, qt, qr-code, qpainter

I am using a third party library : https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator using c++.
So far what I have reached in my code is printing the QR code in the console.

My app generates a pdf file that I write the data entered in some line editors to. I want to add a QR code in that pdf file being generated as well.

```
     QString Widget::generateQRCode(QString name, QString date, QString address, QString email)
    {
            QString data = name + date + address + email
    ;
            const char *text = data.toUtf8().constData();              // User-supplied text
            const QrCode::Ecc errCorLvl = QrCode::Ecc::LOW;  // Error correction level
    
            // Make and print the QR Code symbol
            const QrCode qr = QrCode::encodeText(text, errCorLvl);
            printQr(qr);
            std::cout << toSvgString(qr, 4) << std::endl;
    
            return QString::fromStdString(toSvgString(qr, 4));
    }
```

What I want is to take the output of this function and change it into something I could use the Qpainter class with to insert it into the PDF file.

```
    /*[7] Generate QR Code */

 QString qrcode = generateQRCode(name,date,address,email);
 qDebug()<<"QRCODE QRCODE QRCODE\n"<<qrcode;

 painter.setPen(qRgb(0,0,0));
 painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15, QFont::Bold));
 painter.drawText(500,5000,qrcode);

}
```

Comment: You need to loop over the QR Code modules, and manually draw each square. Look at this TypeScript function for example: [`drawCanvas()`](https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator/blob/4e41cb2c721a5e06eff75e79fd47a4274f6bb8b0/typescript-javascript/qrcodegen-output-demo.ts#L203-L220)

Comment: @Mohmed, I'm reading the generated qr code via an android lib i. zxing, but not able to get the original passed byte. If you have knowledge please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028303/how-to-get-original-bytes-from-the-qr-code-generated-via-a-lvgl